# How to transfer ISO date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to transfer ISO date?

**RangeError: Invalid time value**

```
  handleDateChange = e => {
    let inputDate = e.target.value
    const splited = inputDate.split('/')
    const swaped = [splited[1], splited[0], splited[2]]
    const swappedDate = new Date(swaped)

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: swappedDate.toISOString(),
      bannerText: '',
      birthDate: e.target.value,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. But that is presumably caused by the fact that you are passing an array to the `Date` constructor which is not a common parameter.

Comment: this code is working fine..on which line you are getting invalid time value error?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the order of the date, I would expect this:

Note: I have never seen the date constructor take an array, but it works in Chrome and the month is then 1 based instead of 0 based

```js
const dateString = "10/07/2020"; // dd/mm/yyyy
const splitted = dateString.split('/')
const swapped = [splitted[2], splitted[1], splitted[0]]
const swappedDate = new Date(swapped)
console.log(swappedDate)
// or
const dateString1 = "07/10/2020"; // mm/dd/yyyy
const splitted1 = dateString1.split('/')
const swapped1 = [splitted1[2], splitted1[0], splitted1[1]]
const swappedDate1 = new Date(swapped)
console.log(swappedDate)

// This makes more sense to me

const dateString2 = "10/07/2020"
const [dd,mm,yyyy] = dateString2.split('/')
const swappedDate2 = new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd)
console.log(swappedDate1)
```

Comment: why are you subtracting 1 from month?

Comment: The date constructor is `new Date(yyyy,zero-based-month,dd)` but with the array, it seems to be 1 based